# Increased use of swap on AWS Aurora

Tags: database, amazon-aurora

I have an AWS RDS Aurora (PostgreSQL compatible) instance, which recently triggered an alert because of increased swap usage, which was caused by running some not optimized queries (big temporary tables and sequential scanning). Some basic AWS metrics looks like:

- Blue line: freeable memory
- Purple line: swap usage
- Yellow line: freeable - swap
  [image: AWS RDS Aurora memory usage profile]

I have a few questions I could not find an answer, nowhere in AWS docs, forums nor on SO

1. Why the DB started allocating swap while it still had a lot of freeable memory?
2. Why it's not releasing the swap if it's no longer used? How to reduce the amount of used swap?
3. Why also adds to freeable memory?

Comment: Do you have access to Performance Insights? That can help you to determine which queries were running during that time and the stress they create on the cluster.

Answer (score 0):

You can find more details about the RDS swap memory in the AWS Knowledgebase: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/troubleshoot-rds-swap-memory/.

Swap Memory is an essential part of the OS, which helps to extend the memory size by storing additional data in a DISK. When more memory is allocated, old contents of the RAM is written to the Swap location in the DISK and new contents is placed in the RAM. In this case, it indicates that a new query/a set of queries are executed which fetched/scanned more records thus more RAM is required. So the OS made room by moving some old data to Swap.

As per the KB, below is the reason for swap memory not going down,

> Linux swap usage isn't cleared frequently, because clearing the swap
> usage requires extra overhead to reallocate swap when it's needed and
> when reloading pages. As a result, if swap space is used on your RDS
> DB instance, even if swap space was used only one time, the SwapUsage
> metrics don't return to zero.

Postgres caches the result of previous executions in RAM so that it can reduce the disk seek next time. You can improving the database performance by allocating sufficient buffer cache. This is an expected behavior. The size of this cache is configurable. Please refer: https://redfin.engineering/how-to-boost-postgresql-cache-performance-8db383dc2d8f

Also as mentioned in the KB, this could be due to queries that returns huge amount of record, or a load on the database. You can enable performance insights to get more details about the queries that are running during that time.

BTW, Performance insights may not be available in smaller RDS instances. In that case, you can look in to the binary logs to see which queries where executed. Also enabling slow query logs will help you.